# failed sending template within email

Tags: asp.net, html, email-templates

in asp.net, i am trying to send a template in an email, so when a user will get a message from my website, then it will be in a template,

e.g. when FB sends you a notification via mail, then it has a header and footer too, so i want to do that, i tried but it isn't sending any template within email body

CODE:

```
MailDefinition mailDefinition = new MailDefinition();
                mailDefinition.BodyFileName = "emailBody.htm";
                mailDefinition.From = "hunain.hafeez@gmail.com";

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(user_email);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                message.Subject = "Registration";
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                message.Body = "Congrats" + " " + userName + " " + " You have been shortlisted for interview. Please appear on " + " " + date +", "+time+" "+ "for interview";

                SmtpClient objClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                objClient.EnableSsl = true;


                objClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("hunain.hafeez", "*******");
```

Comment: Log the value of what you are assigning yo the body. A null value can clear this string.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** For quick fix use [**HTML mark-up templates**](http://www.coderewind.com/article/how-to-send-emails-using-html-templates-in-asp-net/) , however a more flexible solution is **Razor** with email templating.

There are different approaches on how to achieve this. However, I stumbled upon a greate article about how to use Razor with email templating.  Razor was pushed with ASP.NET MVC 3, but MVC is not required to use Razor.  This is pretty slick processing of doing email templates

As the article identifies, "The best thing of Razor is that unlike its predecessor(webforms) it is not tied with the web environment, we can easily host it outside the web and  use it as template engine for various purpose. "

[Use Razor for Email Template outside ASP.NET MVC](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/use-razor-for-email-template-outside-asp-dot-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Your message body needs to have HTML markup in it.

ie:

```
<html><body><b>Congrats ....
```

Comment: wait, leeme try, what u said

Comment: Did you get a chance to try that out yet? Any problems I can help you with?

Comment: yes i did, i changed everything but positioning isn't working, actually i want to put HEADER and FOOTER but couldn't :(